# what is omkar Upasana and how to do it? what's its benefit. if you guys have any reference book which was written on omkar Upasana let me know

Tags: shiva, om

what is omkar Upasana and how to do it? what's its benefit. if you guys have any reference book which was written on omkar Upasana let me know.